# Count length of filtered items of a certain category in an array with Vue js

Tags: arrays, vuejs2, count

I have an array which looks like this:

```
{
  "blogs": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Test title 1",
       "category": "tennis",
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Test titel 2",
      "category": "football",
    },
    // etc
}
```

I know I can get the `length` of the array like this `<div>{{ getfilteredData.length }}</div>`.

But how do I count the length of the items of a certain `category`?

**Update:**

I managed to show a category `length`, combined with the active filters. Here is a [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/gallant-stonebraker-vx0y5?file=/src/components/List.vue) of the result.

But now I only defined it for the `category === 'tennis'`. How do I combine this method so it shows independently the `length` of all 3 categories?

**Update 2:**
I managed to do it with a *method* (thanks to the answer of Mohammed) instead of using a *computed property*. With methods you're able to pass parameters.

Comment: `blogs.filter(({category}) => category === 'whatever').length`

Comment: @Robby Cornelissen sorry, I don't get the idea yet. How do I have to use this in my example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use this method:

```
getLengthofaCategory(cat){
  var categoryLength = blogs.filter((item) => item.category == cat);
  return categoryLength.length;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should still use a computed, because if you have it return a object with the counts for each category there is no need to pass a parameter, but rather you specify the category as the object key.  And the way to return an object with the counts is to use `reduce`.  By using a computed, the function only gets executed again if the data it relies on changes, instead of going through the expense of calling `filter` every time, an object access being hundreds of times faster (I once did a jsperf for this)

```
  computed: {
      categoryCount: function() {
          return blogData.blogs.reduce((catCount, blogData) => {
              catCount[blogData.category] = catCount[blogData.category] || 0;
              catCount[blogData.category]++
              return catCount;
          }, {})
      }
    }

    // USAGE: categoryCount['tennis']
```